# How can a Rails scaffold create a new instance of an associated model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, combobox

I am creating my first Rails app, a botanical collection manager. It's a basic CRUD app, but I'm falling down on creating instances of associated models. The primary table is Accessions. An Accession `belongs_to` a "source" (the person or institution from which the accession was acquired). It also `belongs_to` a "taxon" and a "lineage", but they'll be handled the same way when I figure this out, so let's just look at "source".

"Source" is just a name and a notes field. Currently, I've edited the Accession scaffold form like so:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :source_id %><br>
  <%= f.collection_select :source_id, Source.all, :id, :name, include_blank: '' %>
  <%#= f.number_field :source_id %>
</div>
```

I would like to create a composite widget to allow me to select an existing source or create a new one, and was planning on using a jQuery combobox for this. The questions isn't about the front-end code, which I think I'm fine with. I'm just not sure how to tie this all together.

What I would normally do (in, say, an ASP or PHP app) is catch that I'd passed back a source name without a source id, create the source first, and then shim that newly-created source id into the properties map for the to-be-created accession.

How do I go about that in a Rails idiom?

Comment: If you're going to driveby downvote, at least tell me where the answer you think is a duplicate is so I can read it. I've spent about a half hour looking before I asked this.

Comment: You probably got downvoted because it is not clear what you are trying to ask. Are you trying to ask how can you create a new `source` if it didn't exists? You might find this useful http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-or-create-by

Comment: Sorry, I did think that "I would like to . . . select an existing source or create a new one" was clear enough. Thanks for the pointer to that method, though. Could you expound in an answer on how I'd use that (in the view or controller of Accession) to create the new `source`?